# Does my Macbook pro 2015 have windows installed?

Tags: windows, macbook, boot-camp

My daughter thinks I might have installed windows on her Macbook Pro in the distant past, presumably using Boot Camp.  How can I check if this is the case?  The hard disk breakdown is 11.4 system, 56.9 other, apps 24.8, messages 8, bin 5 gb.  The computer is very slow (I know it's old!) and we're wondering if this is part of the problem.

Results of diskutil:

```
diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):    
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER    
    0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
    1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
    2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):

    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER    
    0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1    
                                 Physical Store disk0s2    
    1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     99.3 GB    disk1s1
    2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 84.5 MB    disk1s2
    3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s3
    4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
    5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.4 GB    disk1s5

diskutil cs list

No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

Comment: Open Terminal. Type `diskutil list` & if that gives no useful info, type `diskutil cs list` [one or the other will have good info, the other pretty empty]. Copy/paste that into your question using the [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1729549/edit) button, then select the pasted text & hit Ctrl/k [not cmd, ctrl] to format as code, which is more readable.

Comment: Windows installation will have no impact on performance. It doesn't run in parallel with macOS - you choose which to boot when powering on the computer. When macOS is running, Windows is not, so no performance impact at all.

Comment: I still use a 2015 MacBook Pro and it's still very fast! I did some rough addition on your storage totals and it's almost 110 GB. If you have a 128 GB SSD installed, the nearly full SSD could be part of the slowness.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your responses.  I've screenshotted the responses to diskutil list and diskutil cs list in the next comment.  Do they tell us anything? It's good to hear windows itself isn't slowing it down.  But my concern is the way the SSD is full.  60 gb is devoted to "other" and I was wondering if that might be windows.  But in any case, she should obviously try to get rid of a lot of this.  How can she access it?  Joe

Comment: 1st bit of screenshot: diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0

   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1

   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.1 GB   disk0s2



/dev/disk1 (synthesized):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1

Comment: 2nd bit: /dev/disk1 (synthesized):

   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1
Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     99.3 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 84.5 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.4 GB    disk1s5
diskutil cs list

No CoreStorage logical volume groups found

Comment: Please edit that into your question body as previously advised, so we have a chance to be able to read it properly. It's a mare to try read without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Boot Camp/Windows data on the drive, it is formatted 'Mac only' with correct partitioning & ancillary system volumes.

the issue would appear to be that it's just too full to operate properly. The drive has approximately 6GB of free space, which is far too low for comfort. Time Machine local backups & general data caching will fill that almost constantly when the Mac is running, leaving it almost no room to 'breathe' at all.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space for methods of tracking down where you can make space.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  Now we've located the problem, I hope we can make some headway with it!